# Dont want to show address in the status bar while hovering a link

Tags: html

How can I prevent showing web address at the status bar while hovering a hyperlink?

Comment: If you want to do this because you want to prevent the users to see where the link goes to, then forget about it. One can always have a look at the source code.

Comment: This sounds very sinister to me. Why do you want to achieve this?

Comment: @Felix and danixd, 
Yeah, I bet that on the other end of a link from a person who doesn't know how hide status bar text will be a state-of-the-art hack! :)

Comment: Dont worry people. I was just curious how to do it. Nothing else. Thank you all.

Comment: Maybe it was a FAIL, but I was trying to be ironic... It was a legit question as far as I am concerned... I also did some status bar changes in the past and there was nothing shady about it.

Comment: What about the case where your link executes a function, and does not navigate to a URL?  Yet you still want the link to 'behave' as a link (change mouse to pointer for example), but you don't necessarily want anything in the status bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could change your hyperlink to use JavaScript to navigate to the URL. For example, if you wanted a link to http://conglomo.co.nz/:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="location.href='http://conglomo.co.nz/'">Conglomo</a>
```

Although this is not as pretty as changing window.status (which does not work for everyone due to browser settings) it will hide the URL from the status bar completely.

Comment: It kind of makes it impossible to use tabs =(

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to reliable do this, and no point in doing it either.

Any information the user could get out of the status bar is available to them through other methods, so it can't add security.

If you are worried about aesthetics, then the majority of people who would look at it are more likely to be annoyed by the absence of the normal status information then they would be the URI appearing 'ugly'.

If you really want to try to do this, you can look at [window.status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.status). Happily, most modern browsers allow this feature to be blocked.

Firefox, for example, blocks it by default:

> This property does not work in default configuration of Firefox and some other browsers: setting window.status has no effect on the text displayed in the status bar. To allow scripts to change the the status bar text, the user must set the `dom.disable_window_status_change` preference to false in the `about:config` screen.

Comment: +1 for users being frustrated about the site overriding the status URL. I have realized that I look at the status URL a lot more than I would have otherwise assumed. I like to know where I'm being redirected!

Answer (score 1):

You need javascript for that, not php, you can use `onMouseOver` and `window.status` like:

```
<a href="address" onMouseOver="window.status = ''">A Link</a>
```

**Note:** ***It is not a good practice*** and adept people can find it out easily.

Comment: While not necessarily considered good practise, and useless for hiding the actual URL, it can be used to display a more user-friendly text in the status bar

Comment: @Mark - The users who tend to look at the status bar will tend to find that *less* friendly. Use the `title` attribute for user friendly text.

Comment: @David As a rule I do always use Title