# While mouseover a link, do not show it on the status-bar with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a way to hide a link from the status bar while the mouse is over a link?
I saw something like that that I could not trace-back, it was (as much as I could see) pure CSS. Is that possible at all?

I saw a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207467/how-to-hide-links-on-browsers-statusbar-when-you-mouseover-on-links-on-webpage)
which uses Javascript.
As well as this one:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108425/dont-want-to-show-address-in-the-status-bar-while-hovering-a-link)
which also uses Javascript (and shows in the status bar `javascript:;`)

I look for a pure CSS solution, which will in fact change the mouse to a pointer while over a link and will show no indication in the status bar what-so-ever.
Also - I (obviously) don't mind for the user to see the link if he's able to look through the page source.

This is not for shady activity or such (as I saw written in other answers)

Thanks!

Comment: The statusbar is outside the control of CSS so you need to use JavaScript. The user has the final say if you and your scripts can override the default settings so don't be surprised if your script doesn't work for some users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

Longer answer:

When using anchor html elements for links, e.g. `<a href="...">`, the browser provides the on click behavior and the changing of the status bar. CSS is used for styling, and cannot be used to change the window's status - that's a javascript function.

If you don't use an anchor element, but you use another type of element for which the browser doesn't display status, you need to use some javascript to add a click handler to the element.

In either case, there's no CSS solution to do this.